# Accessing virtual host from all computers on home network

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, virtualhost

I've set up an Apache server on a computer in my home network and enabled name-based virtual hosting. When I enter the URL of the virtual host on that computer in a browser the page is correctly displayed.

I'd also like to be able to access the virtual host from other computers on my home network. All computers are connected to the same router. But I'm not sure what to do next to achieve that.

Can anyone help by pointing me in the right direction?

TIA

Comment: What is a more appropriate site to post this question to?

Comment: Simplest solution is to assign a static IP to the virtual host, and then use a hosts file entry on all other computers in the network, as mentioned by Jon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things you can do here.  First, and maybe easier is to add the hostname of the name-based virtual host to the hosts file of the computer you want to check the page from. This will be /etc/hosts on Linux-like systems.

```
virtual.example.com  192.0.2.42
```

Where virtual.example.com is the value from the name-based virtual host followed by the IP address of the web server.

The other option, is to add a record into DNS for this.  If you have access to and control over the local DNS server, you can add a zone to mimic the configuration from the name-based virtual host.